# How can i show attachments as images in a DataView Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-designer, attachments

I know i can show document attachments this way:

```
<xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
          <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ListId">
                 {27A5A2ED-76FB-4DE3-8206-B4BE32C09CFC} </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
              <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
          </xsl:attribute>

          </xsl:element>
```

But the problem is how can i show it as an image?Not link to the text.
Also how can i have it open in a new window.
In SP 2007 it was possible :(
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you dump just @Attachments in the XSLT, it should return 1 (attachments exist) or 0 (no attachements exist).  From there, you can put in some logic to say that if @Attachments = 1 then create an image to _layouts/images/attach.gif.

Comment: Thanks PirateEcir and Nandy.
But i need the full URL of the attached document.
I want to show the file attached as an image.
Hope i have elaborated enough

Answer (score 0):

You can create calculate column in SharePoint list and show that column in DataView Web Part instead of attachment column field.

Thanks,
Nandy

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why" and "how". Please edit your post with additional details, perhaps an example. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Thanks.